# How to achieve maximum efficiency with underscore's map and filter?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Is it possible to combine Underscore's filter and map? I currently have two separate function calls, but I'm wondering if I can make them more efficient by combining them into a single call, somehow.

Basically I have an array of country names - I want to filter them using a regex, then map the filtered results to an array of DataItem objects. This is my current code:

```
var filteredData = _.filter(allCountries, function(n, i){ 
  var re = RegExp("^" + searchString, "i");
  if (re.exec(n['country'].toLowerCase()) !== null) {
    return true;
  }
});
var mappedData = _.map(filteredData, function(n, i){ 
  return new DataItem(i, n['name'], n['budget']);
});
```

Any other tips for improved efficiency would also be gratefully received.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `each` instead:

```
 result = []
_.each(array, function(elem) {
    if(elem.indexOf(search) == 0)
        result.push(...whatever...)
```

Also note that you don't need a regular expression just to find out if a string starts with another one.

Comment: Chain is much preferred to each

Comment: @itcouldevenbeaboat: can be, I don't use underscore that much... In this particular case `each` seems to be more readable.

Comment: This is not good because now you've introduced the unnecessary, mutable `result` variable. One can argue that you might as well use a `for` loop in this case. `chain` is the preferred way to go.

Answer (score 35):

Underscore offers a chaining ability through `_.chain`:

```
_.chain(allCountries)
 .filter(function(n, i) { ... })
 .map(function(n, i) { ... })
 .value(); // stop chaining and get the result
```

Instead of `re.exec(...) !== null` you can use `re.test(...)`, and note that you need to escape special regexp characters for `searchString`.

In this simple case however, it's better to use `.indexOf` to check whether the string starts with a substring:

```
// substring should be apparent at position 0, discard case for both strings
return n.country.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString.toLowerCase()) === 0;
```

For string literals, `.foo` may be clearer than `['foo']`.

Comment: This is certainly an answer!

Answer (score 11):

Use `_.reduce` as it saves `n` iterations. Pull your RegEx out of the loop so you don't recreate the object every iteration. Use `test` instead of `exec` (faster because it's a simple boolean result).

```
var re = RegExp("^" + searchString, "i");
var data = _.reduce(allCountries, function(res, n, i) { 
  if (re.test(n['country'])) {
    res.push(new DataItem(i, n['name'], n['budget']));
  }
  return res;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 8):

pimvdb's answer is the way we do things in functional programming/underscore.js
it's a bit of a premature optimization to do both steps at the same time. JS doesn't benefit much from doing these things separately.

```
_.chain(allCountries)
 .filter(function(n, i) { ... })
 .map(function(n, i) { ... })
 .value();
```

the above is very easy to understand, but once we start combining responsibilities things get hairy.

_.mapFilter(array,filterFn,mapFn)...

with chaining we are sacrificing performance for productivity. Both are important, but always one is more important than the other. We can't go back and improve productivity, but we can improve performance after the fact.

Comment: This deserves more upvotes! "We can't go back and improve productivity, but we can improve performance after the fact."  Awesome concept!